# Does indemnity insurance (for a house) become void if a 3rd party is told about it?

Tags: united-kingdom, property, insurance

Indemnity insurance is bought if a home's deeds contain a fault, e.g. no access to the property, modifications made by previous owners that are not up to building standards etc.

The insurance would cover loss in the value of the house and some legal fees.

I've heard that indemnity insurance becomes void if a third party is told about the policy. My questions is this claim true for **all** indemnity policies in the UK, or has the claim been made because it is true for only **some** policies?

Comment: Generally, indemnity insurance is bought _in case_ a fault is found in the deed or there might be a planning permission problem. If a problem is already known but not told to the insurer, that could make the policy null-and-void.